# how to select a column value as number or vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i have a column in my sql table that holds the value 'Yes' and 'No'

im copying the table into a new database where the data type of that column has changed from nchar(3) to tinyint

is there a way to select those particular field as numeric into the new table??

e.g. where 'yes' => 1 and where 'No' => 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be using `case`

```
select case when col = 'yes'
            then 1
            else 0
       end as new_col_value
from your_table
```